# Jquery to remove hover from one anchor when i hover another anchor

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I have 3 divs, in each div there is one anchor.

```
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="all"><a href="" >all</a></div>
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="articles"><a href="=" > articles</a></div>
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="interviews"><a href="" >interviews</a></div>
```

Now, when the page loads the anchor should be set automatically to "all", then if i hover over articles or interviews then hover on all should go away and come to either article or interview(wherever the mouse is hovered) and when i come out the article or interview anchor should come back to "all".

Comment: What does all of this mean? Are you talking about styles like the color of the menu item on hover?

Comment: on hover i am mainly doing a increase in font weight and putting a borderline below the the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use css for this, something like this should work:

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="all"><a href="" class="active">all</a>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="articles"><a href="="> articles</a>
</div>
<div class='col-xs-4 sub-heading' id="interviews"><a href="">interviews</a>
</div>
```